# Augmented 6th chord in Haydn String Quartet op.74 no.3, II

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory

In measure 34, we modulate from C major to E minor. In m. 36, the notes played are C in the bass; E, F♯, and G in the viola; G, F♯, E in the second violin; and a whole note A♯ in the first violin. I labeled the chord as Fr+6/(third degree) but my TA says it is a Ger+6/(third degree). Can someone explain this? I can't build this chord. When I try, I get A♭, C, E, F♯ but the passage has an A♯ and not a A♭.

Comment: Welcome to the site! We don't do homework for people here because it's unlikely to help other people.  Unfortunately, Patrx2 has already given a great answer, so it would be great if you could edit your question to be a bit more broad - such as making it clear that you're asking about Aug6 chords, citing the Haydn as an example (and removing the bit about the TA). Free Advice: When you analyze theory, ask yourself how it *sounds*, not every not is equally important; remember the larger picture.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's the bar in question (4th bar in the system):

[image]

So, the notes in the chord are (SATB order): A♯, G, E & C. We can ignore the F♯s - they are pretty much passing tones between the chord tones.

Now, a French sixth on a C bass would be (again SATB order) A♯, F♯, E & C - French sixths are whole tone chords that tend to act like a gapped dominant seventh chord to the following chord (in this case, F♯7 moving to B7) over the *descending* leading tone to the following harmony (in this case, C-B in the bass).

The German sixth, however, uses the same tones as a dominant 7th built on the bass as a root, but spelt differently as the "seventh" *ascends* to the tonic of the following chord (rather than descending to the third of a chord a fifth below), thus acting as an augmented sixth. Note that the German sixth is *not* a whole tone chord.

Check the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_sixth_chord). The German sixth has parallel fifth problems not inherent in the French sixth, and Haydn went out of his way to avoid them here.

**Edit:** what your TA meant by Ger+6/3 was a first inversion chord - the C in the bass is the third of the chord, with A♯ as the "root" of the chord (forming a diminished third with C; when placed in first inversion, A♯ forms an augmented sixth with C).

The distinguishing trait of all augmented sixth chords is that they have *two* leading tones to the root of the following chord, a descending "Phrygian" leading tone in the bass, and an ascending leading tone in an upper voice (usually the descant). *The harmonic function of augmented sixth chords is determined by melodic movement, not root movement.*

Indeed, for French sixths, determining a harmonic root for the chord isn't really possible: if you invert the chord so that (in our case) G♭ (F♯) is in the bass, you have another French sixth that moves to the root a tritone away from the original destination (in our case, that would be F rather than B). This kind of indeterminacy is common with whole tone chords. The French sixth, however, functions just like the other forms of augmented sixth because of the two leading tones.

Comment: The basic "flavour" of the German 6th has been somewhat obscured by Equal Temperament tuning. In ET, the chords C E G A# and C E G Bb are identical. In the unequal temperaments of Haydn's time, A# was *not* the same note as Bb. The C E G A# chord sounded best resolving onto B major, each note moving by a semitone (that ignores the issue of consecutive 5ths, of course) whereas C E G Bb sounded best resolving as the dominant 7th of F major. In equal temperament, the tritone interval between the resolutions on F and B is analogous to tritone chord substitutions in jazz harmony.

Comment: @alephzero, not quite. Haydn's time used well-tempered tunings (Young, Vallotti, etc.) - not equal, but re-entrant. B♭ and A♯ would be effectively the same note, but the intervals formed with other members of the chromatic scale would not be in neat multiples of 100 cents - the comma was distributed so as to give preferential purity to C major while avoiding wolf fifths in more distant keys and closing the cycle of fifths. That being said, string players would tend to shrink semitones in the direction of movement by adjusting the leading tones, _and they still do_.

Answer (score 1):

It's a German 6th resolving on (and temporarily tonicizing) B major which is the dominant of E major - the key of the new section.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you're running into is deciding your local key; you are expecting A♭, C, E, and F♯ because that's the Ger+6 in the key of C. (Actually, it would be E♭, not E♮; use the minor third scale degree, just like you use the minor sixth scale degree in the bass.)

Since you're moving to E (as you said), we'll build it on the same scale degrees: (♭)6, 1, (♭)3, and ♯4: C, E, G, A♯. [Note that by (♭) before these scale degrees I mean they're the lowered version. In major we have to actively lower them a half step, but in minor the key signature handles that for us.)

Comment: Nope. The German sixth only differs from the root position dominant seventh on the bass note by interpreting the seventh as an augmented sixth. Augmented sixth chords derive from the Phrygian cadence, which is iv6 - V (- i or I). In E major, iv6 would be A minor with C in the bass. The Italian sixth sharps the root (A in this case) to create a leading tone to the dominant; the other two add another tone to the It+6 to smooth the voiceleading. _All_ of them work around a base (in the key of E) of A♯, E & C.

Comment: We're saying the same thing in two different ways; I was mainly trying to address OP's remark of "When I try, I get A flat, C, E, F# when the passage has an A# and not a A flat." It was clear s/he was thinking in C, not in E.

Comment: Ah, OK. I never even considered a key of C because it is, _at very best_, a passing tonality here, so this caught me a bit off-guard - the previous two bars strongly suggest a move through A minor to 2nd inversion E minor just prior to the augmented sixth, so I assumed that the cadence in E was quite clear, and we had a misunderstanding of how German sixths were spelt. My bad.